# How to get window with proper layout on clicking menu item

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, layout-manager

I'm developing my first java desktop application. I have created on frame which is shown as below:

[image: Home Page]

and on clicking on "File" menu item I want such a view which asks to user about his Name, Contact No. and Email Address and also can store image. I can create frame on clicking on file as shown as below:

[image: Add New Contact]

Please help me to get the proper layout I have searched for different layouts and here used is `BoxLayout` for 2nd screen.

Answer (score 3):

> Please help me to get the proper layout..

[`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) is what you are looking for to flip between different 'views'.

You might put a `loginPanel` into it for the log-in details, and for that panel I would probably use a [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html).  But also consider showing the log-in in a modal `JDialog`.  To me it looks odd to have a log-in embedded in the main GUI.

Comment: can u get me some examples for CardLayout?

Comment: Can you spell simple words like 'you' properly?  Can you put an upper case letter at the start of your sentences to make your words easier to read?  Can you be bothered to read the tutorial for `CardLayout` long enough to realize it ***has*** examples?  If you expect me to spoon-feed an example to you, it will end in disappointment.